# How do I change the width of scrollbars in Gnome?

Tags: gnome, scrollbar

How do I change the width of scrollbars in Gnome?

The option to configure this is not in the "Appearance" application in the Preferences menu.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In the file `~/.gtkrc-2.0`, add the following lines:

```
style "wide-scrollbar-style"
{
  GtkScrollbar::slider_width = 24
}
widget_class "*Scrollbar" style "wide-scrollbar-style"
```

Answer (score 1):

`sudo apt-get install gnome-color-chooser`

Then launch: *System → Preferences → GNOME Color Chooser*.
Under the "Specific" tab, you can change the scroll bar width. Then Click Apply.

[image: Screenshot of GNOME Color Chooser]

Comment: Doesn't work at least on Ubuntu 17.10