# How do you configure the appearance of scrollbars in Firefox 57?

Tags: firefox, kde

In KDE 5.40 on openSUSE Tumbleweed, I have configured scrollbars to look and work like this:

[image]

However in Firefox, scrollbars are different. Note the lack of buttons at the end of each bar and being too slim:

[image]

The solutions from [How do I change the width of scrollbars in Gnome?](https://superuser.com/questions/346491/how-do-i-change-the-width-of-scrollbars-in-gnome) unfortunately only work on applications from ca. 2009.

Comment: I think firefox ignores the theme / window manager settings and uses whatever scrollbar it prefers. Only vaguely related, but [this Q on AskUbuntu](https://askubuntu.com/questions/295988/how-to-fix-gtk3-scrollbar-behavior) might be worth trying, basically `echo -e "[Settings]\ngtk-primary-button-warps-slider = false" >> ~/.config/gtk-3.0/settings.ini` (if the file already exists take a look at it first) + restart Firefox, and it's easy to undo if it doesn't work

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The styles from `/usr/share/themes/*/gtk-3.20/gtk.css` need to be overridden. Because the GTK-tards changed yet once again how the system works for no good reason, many previous solutions to the problem stopped working.

[The CSS class is now `scrollbar`, was previously `.scrollbar`. `-GtkRange-slider-width` and `-GtkRange-stepper-size` were apparently removed, use `min-width`/`min-height` on the widget element instead.](https://askubuntu.com/a/908584)

---

My content of `~/.config/gtk-3.0/gtk.css`:

```css
scrollbar, scrollbar button, scrollbar slider {
    -GtkScrollbar-has-backward-stepper: true;
    -GtkScrollbar-has-forward-stepper: true;
    min-width: 25px;
    min-height: 25px;
    border: 1px solid #5d9797;
    border-radius: 0;
}
scrollbar slider {
    background: theme_bg_color;
}
scrollbar slider:hover {
    border-color: #418bd4;
}
```

Looks like this; close enough for me.

[image]